# rundeck: cannot authenticate to API

Tags: java, authentication, httprequest, rundeck

I'm using rundeck solution on windows server 2012 R2 with the launcher. I cannot authenticate to the API. I created a token from admin's account and even try the second authentication solution username/password with admin account credentials (the ones I log in to the rundeck GUI) but I always get the same kind of error...

```
<result error="true" apiversion="20">
   <error code="unauthorized">
     <message>
       (unauthenticated) is not authorized for: /api/20/projects
     </message>
   </error>
</result>
```

I've no more ideas how to solve this. Could someone give me a hand please?

Cheers guys,
Kevin

Comment: Can you log in web ui using your admin credentials?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - Did not understand the post request has to be of content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded